# Update Dynamic Oracle from another table when the table have the same column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update

I have two tables, the first table is "tes_tmp" and the second table is "tes_tmp1". I want to update the "tes_tmp1" table based on the "tes_tmp" table. If there are matching columns between the two tables, then "tes_tmp1" should be updated.

i have already tried the following query:

```
MERGE INTO TES_TMP1 t1
USING (SELECT * FROM tes_tmp) t2
   ON (t1.objectid = t2.objectid)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE SET t1.kecamatan = t2.kecamatan, T1.wilayah = T2.wilayah;
```

However, in the above query, required to declare each column explicitly. my question is whether there is a way to update the table without explicitly declaring the columns first.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you'll have to specify all columns you want to update, one by one. No *shortcuts*. Though, you could try to write query which will write query for you which might pay off if there are 100s of columns in that table.

Comment: so there is no way to update without declaring columns even with dynamic sql ?

Comment: You can build an update statement you want and run it with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Comment: That's what I meant by "write query which will write query for you". If you think it's wort the effort, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is whether there is a way to update the table without explicitly declaring the columns first.

No.

The [documented syntax for `MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/MERGE.html) is:

> #### merge::=
>
> [image: MERGE syntax diagram]
>
> Note:You must specify at least one of the clauses `merge_update_clause` or `merge_insert_clause`.
>
> #### merge_update_clause::=
>
> [image: MERGE update clause syntax]
>
> #### merge_insert_clause::=
>
> [image: MERGE insert clause syntax]

In both the `MERGE` insert and update clauses there is no defined syntax to use a wildcard; you have to explicitly state the columns that are going to be merged.

---

If you want to build some dynamic SQL then you will need code to:

- automatically list the columns in both tables;
- calculate which of those columns need to be updated;
- use string concatenation to dynamically build an SQL statement; and
- then run it using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance. Now I am able to perform updates without declaring the columns beforehand.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE tes_update
IS
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT column_name
            FROM user_tab_columns
            WHERE table_name = 'TES_TMP'
              AND column_name IN (SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'TES_TMP1'))
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE tes_tmp1 t2
                       SET t2.' || c.column_name || ' = (SELECT t1.' || c.column_name || ' FROM tes_tmp t1 WHERE t1.objectid = t2.objectid AND ROWNUM = 1)
                       WHERE t2.objectid IN (SELECT objectid FROM tes_tmp t1 WHERE t1.' || c.column_name || ' IS NOT NULL)';
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Update successful!');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Update failed: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```